# Downloading OpenStreetMap data for one state of USA?

Tags: openstreetmap, united-states

I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/openstreetmap-tile-server-ubuntu-16-04)

It has following instrucions to download the data:

1)  Planet download:

```
wget -c http://planet.openstreetmap.org/pbf/planet-latest.osm.pbf
```

2) This for Great britain:

```
wget -c http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/great-britain-latest.osm.pbf
```

Both works, but I don't find how to download USA data, I have tried this:

```
wget -c http://download.geofabrik.de/north-america/usa/california-latest.osm.pbf
```

I'm working on a remote server, hence I can't use the browser to do download the file.

But I get 404 error:

```
 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Comment: I don't know how you got the URL for California, visit http://download.geofabrik.de/north-america.html to get http://download.geofabrik.de/north-america/us/california-latest.osm.pbf. Just one letter less.

Comment: I just copied the file name and replace "europe/great-britain-latest.osm.pbf" for "usa/california-latest.osm.pbf"

Comment: Geofabrik preferred to name the folder `us` instead of `usa`.

Comment: great, it was that.